# Complex WordPress Website

Tags: multisite

So I think this is where this post should go, but let me know if I'm wrong.

So, I work at a small dev/design firm. and we recently got a big client that has a somewhat complex website. We're currently in the design stage, but are thinking forward for developing it, and how we should proceed.

The main requirement is that it has to be CMS controlled and easy for them to jump in and make edits, so we're going forward with WordPress (our normal development).

A bit about our normal workflow, We use WordPress with the Elementor Page Builder(and some add-ons). Most of our sites are simple, with pages built out in elementor, with some plugins. I'm not averse to jumping into the WordPress loop and managing custom themes or creating JavaScript WordPress plugins but most of our clients don't need anything like that.

So this client, has two physical locations, each servicing different audiences. Because of this, they want a splash page to direct them to either site and ideally for it to all show up within the same URL Structure.

www.domain.com/splash-page/

www.domain.com/location1/page

www.domain.com/location2/page

But each location will have its own navbar/footer and its own content. The design will the same/ish, but the content will change. Which sounds like each location needs to have its own WordPress install. What I've been wondering is if it's possible to manage two websites and a splash page all within one WordPress install with the considerances above.

My first thought was to install WordPress into subfolders of the domain. but this would require them to manage the site in three locations, which isn't really optimal.

Has anyone approached this sort of site structure before or have any suggestions on how to build this site?

Answer (score 3):

From my perspective, you have 3 options:

1. WordPress Multisite.
2. 2 separate WordPress sites with a common landing page.
3. 1 WordPress site with custom logic to determine content (store location).

Each direction has disadvantages, but each of them is possible and will result in a perfectly fine end product.

I cannot provide a recommendation. You need to determine the best course of action based on your comfort level, skills, and the needs of the client.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've spent some time looking into it, and I like the WordPress Multisite route (I did a quick set up of it to test out how it may work). Is there anything about that direction that you think I should take into consideration?

Comment: Sharing content between sites is complicated and not supported out of the box, hosts don't always support multisite, and think through the process of setting up a new location as a new site ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a custom menu and locations.

So if current page matches location a, display menu_a, and display menu_b if page is location b?

That can be done with some code that calls a custom menu if the page id matches your selected page.

You should be able to do this in Elementor using Templates for the footer and menus on the pages you want as well.